# Return statement in void method

Tags: java

I have the following method that returns void and I need to use it in another method that also returns void. 
Can I do the following?

```
public void doSomething(){}

public void myMethod()
{
    return doSomething();
}
```

Thanks for all your comments, but let me be more specific

I only `doSomething` if something happens, otherwise I do other things

```
public void doSomething(){}

public void myMethod()
{
    for(...)
        if(somethingHappens)
        {
            doSomething();
            return;
        }

    doOtherStuff();
}
```

Instead of the code above, can I just write `return doSomething();` inside the if statement?

Comment: Also, make sure you keep your capitalization right. `Return` should be `return` and `Public` should be `public`.

Comment: is it possible to return something when you are using void?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, just do this:

```
public void doSomething() { }

public void myMethod()
{
    doSomething();
}
```

or in the second case:

```
public void doSomething() { }

public void myMethod()
{
    // ...
    if (somethingHappens)
    {
        doSomething();
        return;
    }
    // ...
}
```

"Returning void" means returning nothing. If you would like to "jump" out of `myMethod`'s body, use `return;` The compiler does not allow writing `return void;` ("illegal start of expression") or `return doSomething();` ("cannot return a value from method whose result type is void"). I understand it seems logical to return "void" or the "void result" of a method call, but such a code would be misleading. I mean most programmers who read something like `return doSomething();` would think there is *something* to return.

Comment: if I use `return` for an if statement inside a `void` function, it would simply leave (jump out) the function!

Answer (score 5):

void functions don't/can't return anything as such. Simply call the function.

Answer (score 2):

No, returns are unnecessary in Java void functione. Instead, do this:

```
public void myMethod(){
    doSomething();
}
```

You could put a return after doSomething() if you wanted, but as I said it'd be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You either have to just use doSoemthing like the others have pointed out OR

```
public (insert data type like int, double, string, etc) myMethod()
{
     return doSomething();
}
```

If do something returns an int

```
// if you wanted to take 2 numbers and add them

public void myMethod()
{
    valueOfX+Y = doSomething();
}

public int doSomething()
{
    x = 2;
    y = 2;
    return X+Y;
}
```

hope that clears it up

Answer (score 0):

If

- the condition `(somethingHappens)` actually depends on what `doSomething()` did
- and `doSomething()` is a method you can modify

then you should consider making it return the `boolean` (or any suitable type) value which tells the callee method if it happened or not.

Code would then look somewhat like this:

```
public boolean doSomething() {
    // internal working
    if (internalCondition) {
         // something done here
         return true;
    }
    // not done ;
    return false;
}

public void myMethod()
{
    for(...)
        if (doSomething())
        {
            return;
        }
    // didn't hit 'doSomething() == true'
    doOtherStuff();
}
```