# Why do we use return; statement in a void function?

Tags: c

`return;` in a `void` function. What does it actually do?

```
void function() {
    if(x==NULL) {
        return;
    }
    else{
        /////
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In the example you've shown, the `return` does nothing.  But think about this example:

```
void do_the_thing()
{
    if(it's already done)
        return;

    do the thing;
}
```

If doing the thing is expensive, or causes problems if it's been done already, you'd like logic like this.  And, besides "expense", there are plenty of reasons a function might choose to do less than its full repertoire of actions during any given call.

In other words, returning from a void function, although it won't return a value, will at least keep the function from doing any of its later stuff.

(Now, with that said, having a `return` in the middle of the function isn't the only way of achieving such a thing.  Instead of `if` statements that cause the function to return early, you could use `if` statements or `else` clauses to cause the function to only do things if it needs to.  Returning to my example, you could also write

```
void do_the_thing()
{
    if( ! already done) {
       do the thing;
    }
}
```

And this leads to an eternal style debate, namely, whether it's a good or bad idea to have multiple `return` statements sprinkled through a function, or if there should always be exactly one, at the end.)

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement when encountered causes the function to return immediately instead of continuing to run any code that comes after it.

If the function returns a value, the `return` statement must specify a value to return.  For a function with a `void` return type, no value is needed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: What dialect(s) of C support that?

Comment: @ScottHunter: The `comefrom` alternative to `goto` is an old joke I used to point out this answer’s before/after mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, this is done to short-circuit the execution, meaning that the remaining code in the function won't be executed (the else statement wouldn't be evaluated or anything else in the function.

This helps from the performance aspect, but also from a defensive programming standpoint as you are setting exactly where the execution returns instead of assuming it will get to the end of the function correctly even though it doesn't need to (code could be accidentally added or changed and affect the expected behavior)

Answer (score 1):

It causes the function (not the program, just that function) to terminate w/o doing anything further.

Answer (score 1):

You use `return` to stop the function without running all the code.

Using your example:

```
void function(){
  if(x==NULL){
     return;
  }
  else{
       /////
  }
  ... some other code here ...
}
```

If `x` is `NULL` then the function is stopping and doesn't run `... some other code here ...`.

If `x` is `not NULL` then the program will execute what is on `else` statement and also `... some other code here ...`

Comment: The `else` is not necessary here as the `return` will bail out of the function. All code after that `if` will run only if the `if` did not fire.

Comment: @tadman the else construction is part of the OP's example that Cosmin was extending for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I'm just adding a note here not necessarily saying that this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

During my time in programming in C++, I learned that '*void functions*' have no *return-type*. A *return-type* is used to declare functions, like `int main()` where the type `int` is a return type and the function has to return an integer value to imply successful termination. However, when we use the `void` function, things change. The *return-type*, `void`; as the name suggests, means that it will not return a value, it will not return anything as it is void - empty. Hence, if you try to return a value from a method (*function*) that is declared void, you will get a compiler error.

But if like you suggested:

```
void function() {    
if(x==NULL) {
    return;
}
else{
    /////
}
```

}

The above code will also, once again give an error because the void method is not built to return values. If the function is of return-type `int` only then will this retrun command work, but a return statement cannot be used in a void function as it gives an error.

I hope that helped you!

For further reading you can visit:
http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~cop3014p/lectures/ch7/index.html

[Return statement in void method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988868/return-statement-in-void-method)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html